# posting on friends facebook wall using Iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-wall

I want to make an iPhone application through which users can post on their friends wall, i know how to post on my own wall but can't post on friends wall.

What do I need to do to get the desired result for Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first time get friend get friend list

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

then select friend and post his/her wall

```
 [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"frined_ID/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```